# How do you share a custom task in a SBT multi-project

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a project set up as a SBT multi-build. That looks like this:

```
- project
   Dependencies.scala
- core
   build.sbt
- server
   build.sbt
build.sbt
```

I want to use `Dependencies.scala` as a container for version numbers of libraries that are shared between the sub-projects.

```
sealed trait Dependencies {
  val commonsIo = "2.4"
}

object DependencyVersions extends Dependencies
```

In the root build.sbt I added a `Setting` that is given to each sub-project.

```
lazy val dependencies = settingKey[Dependencies]("versions")

val defaultSettings = Defaults.coreDefaultSettings ++ Seq(
    dependencies := DependencyVersions)

def projectFolder(name: String, theSettings: Seq[Def.Setting[_]] = Nil) = Project(name, file(name), settings = theSettings)

lazy val core = projectFolder("core", defaultSettings)
```

I can't access the `dependencies` setting in `core/build.sbt`.

```
"commons-io" % "commons-io" % dependencies.value.commonsIo, <-- doesn't work
```

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define common settings (dependencies) in an `object Common extends AutoPlugin` (in `project/Common.scala`), and then use `.enablePlugin(Common)` on sub-project descriptor (see it in [Anorm](https://github.com/playframework/anorm/blob/master/project/Common.scala)).

Answer (score 3):

Thanks @cchantep got it working now using the `AutoPlugin` below

```
import sbt._

sealed trait Dependencies {
  val commonsIo = "2.4"
}

object DependencyVersions extends Dependencies

object DependencyVersionsPlugin extends AutoPlugin {
  override def trigger = allRequirements

  object autoImport {
    lazy val dependencies = settingKey[Dependencies]("Bundles dependency versions")
  }

  import autoImport._

  override def projectSettings = Seq(
    dependencies := DependencyVersions
  )
}
```